# UWP MasterDetailsView Swap Master/Details Panels

Tags: uwp, master-detail, windows-community-toolkit

I was looking for master details view example for my next project. I have successfully compiled and run masterdetailsview example given in Windows Community Toolkit Sample App.

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview) I know that

> The MasterDetailsView Control presents items in a master/details pattern. It shows a collection of items within the "master panel" and the details for that item within the "details panel".

As we know master-panel is displayed on left and details-panel is displayed on right by default in masterdetailsview.

What I want is to swap both of these panels.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style of MasterDetailsView to Swap Master and Details Panels. In the style of MasterDetailsView, there are two columns represent Master and Details Panels, you can swap the layout and then deal with some details after the exchange. You can copy the following style to apply to your view.

.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MasterDetailsViewStyle1" TargetType="controls:MasterDetailsView">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:MasterDetailsView">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="NoSelectionWide" To="HasSelection">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DrillInThemeAnimation ExitTargetName="NoSelectionPresenter" EntranceTargetName="SelectionDetailsPanel"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="NoSelectionNarrow" To="HasSelection">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="200" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenterTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0">
                                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="0" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionDetailsPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1">
                                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="HasSelection" To="NoSelectionWide">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DrillOutThemeAnimation ExitTargetName="SelectionDetailsPanel" EntranceTargetName="NoSelectionPresenter"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="HasSelection" To="NoSelectionNarrow">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenterTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="200"/>
                                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.08" Duration="0:0:0.17" From="1" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionDetailsPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0">
                                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="0" Storyboard.TargetName="MasterPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1">
                                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionWide">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="SelectionDetailsPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="MasterPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="HasSelectionWide">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="NoSelectionPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="MasterPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="HasSelectionNarrow">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="MasterPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="NoSelectionPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionNarrow">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="NoSelectionPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="SelectionDetailsPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="MasterPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WidthStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="MasterColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DetailsColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DetailsPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                                            <Setter Target="NoSelectionPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="MasterPanel.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Target="MasterPanel.Width" Value="NaN"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="WideState"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="RootPanel">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailsColumn" Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MasterColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid x:Name="MasterPanel" Grid.Column="1" Background="{TemplateBinding MasterPaneBackground}" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="{TemplateBinding MasterPaneWidth}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding MasterHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding MasterHeader}" Margin="12,0" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                                    <ListView x:Name="MasterList" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyleSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" IsTabStop="False" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="MasterCommandBarPanel" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="DetailsPanel">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NoSelectionPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding NoSelectionContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding NoSelectionContent}"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="SelectionDetailsPanel">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="DetailsPresenterTransform"/>
                                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Button x:Name="MasterDetailsBackButton" Background="Transparent" Height="44" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="48">
                                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Back"/>
                                            </Button>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="DetailsHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding DetailsHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding DetailsHeader}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="DetailsPresenter" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding DetailsTemplate}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <Grid x:Name="DetailsCommandBarPanel" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<Grid>
    <controls:MasterDetailsView Style="{StaticResource MasterDetailsViewStyle1}" ...>
    ......
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
</Grid>
```